# how can i create a report with two- column page layout?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I'm trying to create a document using RMarkdown with an output in Word, the question I have is how can I make my text is a 2 columns style paper. 
This is the text I want to make 2 columns:

```
---title: "REPORT"
output:
word_document
---


### _1.INTRODUCTION_


 The objective of this report ...

* Section 2 - Summary
 Section 2 presents summary tables per Transmission Zone 
* Section 3 - Voltage Margin
Let $\Delta V_1 > 0$ and $\Delta V_3 > 0$ be the maximum
```

Thanks

Comment: Pandoc (which is used by `rmarkdown`) currently uses `longtable` which does not work in `twocolumn` mode. There are LaTeX-specific ways addressing this (e.g., [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161431/how-to-solve-longtable-is-not-in-1-column-mode-error), [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pandoc-discuss/WV1fVMw_9Ts)), but I haven't seen a "solid change" to pandoc to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can embed HTML in markdown, you might be able to do this with the [related CSS Styling](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp) such as column-count.

Unfortunately, these CSS Attributes are rather new and not implemented by all browsers or tools.